# Angular JS filter to hide and show rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to show and hide rows based on user selection. But its not working properly. Need help
**HTML Code**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in ListOrders |filter:Listfiltering">
     {{x}}
 <td><span ng-bind="x.order_id"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.equipment_name"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.Dept_Name"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.assign_date_time"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.emp_name"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.task_type_name"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-bind="x.maintenance_type_name"></span></td>
    <td ng-show="x.order_status>0&&x.order_status<2"><span>Initiated </span></td>
    <td ng-show="x.order_status>1&&x.order_status<3"><span>Performed </span></td>
    <td ng-show="x.order_status>2"><span>Completed </span></td>

  </tr>
```

**Controller Code**

```
orderlist.filter('Listfiltering', function() {
 return function (x) {
    if(x.order_status==$scope.OrderStatus)
    {
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  };
  });
```

Comment: Your filter can be simplified to `return x.order_status==$scope.OrderStatus;`.

Comment: You misunderstood what filters are. In the angular expression `x in array | filter: argument`, `filter` is a filter. Yes, it's confusing. So when you define a filter `Listfiltering` you should use it as `var | Listfiltering`.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
//controller file
$scope.filterFunc = function (x) {
  return x.order_status==$scope.OrderStatus;
};
//html file
<tr ng-repeat="x in ListOrders |filter:filterFunc">
```

Answer (score 0):

your filter should be written this way

```
orderlist.filter('Listfiltering', function() {
  return function(x, condition) {
    return x.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order_status === condition;
    });
  };
});
```

and use it in template as below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in ListOrders | Listfiltering: OrderStatus">
```

```js
var orderlist = angular.module("app", []);
orderlist.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.ListOrders = [{
    order_id: 1,
    order_status: 'x',
    Dept_Name: 'name1'
  }, {
    order_id: 2,
    order_status: 'x',
    Dept_Name: 'name2'
  }, {
    order_id: 3,
    order_status: 'xx',
    Dept_Name: 'name3'
  }];
});

orderlist.filter('Listfiltering', function() {
  return function(x, condition) {
    if (!condition || condition === '') return x;
    return x.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order_status === condition;
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h2>input 'x' and 'xx' to see filter results</h2>
  <input type="text" ng-model="OrderStatus">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in ListOrders | Listfiltering: OrderStatus">
      <td><span ng-bind="x.order_id"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="x.Dept_Name"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```